# Rubrics using Markdown

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to citate a book or article using Markdown ?

For example: As wrote [MisterKnow][1], it is not possible.

[1]: Mister Know, The Book of Markdown syntax, 2015

This would render a link in [MisterKnow][1] and when you click on it, it would move you to [1].

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported as a standard Markdown feature. Additionally, I am not aware of any non-standard extensions which support such a feature.

I see two ways to address this:

1. If the Markdown implementation you are using supports footnotes, then use a footnote. Note that while footnotes are non-standard (they are not officially defined in the rules), the feature has been supported by many implementations for many years and is rather consistent across the implementations which support it. To use your example:

   ```
   As wrote *Mister Know*[^1], it is not possible.

   [^1]: *Mister Know*, The Book of Markdown syntax, 2015
   ```
2. If the markdown implementation you are using supports it, write your own extension which implements a custom feature that fits your specific needs. Without more information, its hard to say whether this would be possible or what would be required to accomplish this.